# Tap Gesture Recognizer and UIControl

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I've a view controller with UISegmentedControl and UITableView as its children. In `-viewDidLoad` I create a UITapGestureRecognizer and add it to the controller's main view.

When I tap on, for instance, a cell of the table view, the tap gesture recognizer's action is being called and it prevents receiving touches to the table view (that's ok as `tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView == YES`).

However, the issue is that when I tap on the segmented control, the tap gesture recognizer's action is not being called. Why is it so? How to make the tap gesture recognizer the "top" object which handles touches?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: call your tap gesture recognizer's action in your segmented control action method...it works

Comment: @raki: I can do that, but I would like to know why it works in this way.

Comment: there is no terrible logic behind that,simply we are calling tap gesture action method directly from segment action method without influence of tap gesture